# python read from file desriptor 3

Tags: python, stderr

I need to read stream from FD 3(STDERR) in Python.

In perl I would do this:

```
# Open the audio file descriptor
$audio_fh->fdopen( 3, "r" );

$bytes_read = $audio_fh->read($buffer, 80000)
```

How do I do the same in Python?

Comment: Standard error is file descriptor 2.

Answer (score 5):

Use `os.fdopen` to get a file object for a file descriptor.

```
import os
audio_fh = os.fdopen(3)

buffer = audio_fh.read(80000)
```

You can also read directly from the file descriptor with

```
buffer = os.read(3, 80000)
```